# Encrypted user credentials when they are transmitted

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography

How can we encrypted user credentials when they are transmitted with php? (in login forms)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"user credentials" are **not just** the username and password.  A user credential is any data that is used for authentication.  There is no point in using https for the login page if you just spill the session id a few milliseconds later by using http.  The session id,  is a credential and must be protected just like a username/password.

You **must** use https for the **entire** session.  Spilling the session id over HTTP is a clear violation of The OWASP top 10: [Broken Authentication and Session Management](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management).

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself.

Comment: @Ian P use https all of the time,  read the owasp top 10,  don't bother me.

Comment: Rook, Could you please take a look at this link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087483/a-book-or-tutorial-about-secure-user-management-and-privileges
Thank you very much.

Comment: While true, 99% of sites *don't* do this, because session cookies are (supposed to be) only valid for a short time, meaning the only real threat was the rare, individual targeted attack.  This wasn't a big deal when cookie-sniffing was a detailed attack requiring a lot of expertise; however, it has recently become [much more of a problem](http://wp.me/pV3mA-2J).  Nowadays **all sites should use https all the time while authenticated.**

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft  I totally agree,  however Jeff Atwood does not (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-so-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft/69349).  Perhaps you could put in a comment?

Answer (score 3):

The best method is to use ssl (an https page) for your login

Comment: I would have given you a +1 but there is no point in using https for the login page if you just spill the session id a few milliseconds later.  Read the owasp top 10.

Comment: @The Rook well, more or less. You can make certain actions require another you confirm your credentials. And since the users frequently recycle their passwords, they are less exposed even if someone is listening.

Comment: @Artefacto yeah but your still going to get hacked due to a owap violation.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use a form action that's a https url, e.g.:

```
<form action="https://example.com/target.php" method="post">
```

Alternatively, you could do some kind of digest authentication. The server would send a nonce and a challenge and you, via javascript, would use that data and the password to build a digest you'd send the server for it to check. For an example, see [HTTP digest authentication](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html).

Comment: Nope. HTTPS only works if the entire session is protected by it. Without covering the entire session, you can only save your password from being stolen at best, but why does the attacker care about your password when he can have your session?

Comment: @Lon Because e.g. certain privileged actions may require that you provide your credentials again; because the session may be restricted to a IP; because the session has a time limit; because the password, which users regularly recycle, is not exposed, etc. Yes, the only completely safe solution is to encrypt **everything**, and not just the session, also the form in which the credentials are submitted, otherwise an active attacker could change the form action.

Comment: way to take what I said literally. Encrypting the entire session usually implies all the data passed between the client and server is encrypted. And no, asking for authentication at certain points is insecure because there's no way to ensure a fake proxy session isn't setup by the attacker. Once you leave HTTPS there is no going back.

Comment: @Lon You changed the needed assumptions between the two commentaries. While your first one required only a passive attacker, now you require an active one. And you ignored the other mitigating factors for session cookie sniffing. Anyway, this discussion is pointless. We know that protection against active attackers requires encryption and a PKI or a chain of trust. My argument was never that encrypting the login data was super-secure, it was that it may mitigate or even prevent most attacks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the following to prevent the password being sent over the line in plain text:

- Use HTTPS.
- Use [HTTP Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) authentication.
- Encrypt the password using Javascript.

Comment: Encrypt the password using Javascript is not a good option. How would you give the client the secret securely (the key with which to encrypt the password)? You'd have to use https or use a diffie-hellman key exchange.

Comment: It is possible to do SHA1 in Javascript. This way, the password hash can not be decrypted but it can be checked against the database. There are also people who try to do Diffie-Hellman in Javascript.

Comment: Unlike Digest and SSL, a Javascript encryption does not protect against man-in-the-middle attacks. But it DOES encrypt the traffic, thus prevents sniffing. Incomplete, but worlds better than a plain form.

Comment: Digest access authentication is also vulnerable to Man-in-the-middle attack, if used over HTTP. For example, a MitM attacker could tell clients to use Basic access authentication.

Comment: @Sjoerd Your reasoning is wrong. If you hash the password and send it to the server to authenticate yourself, you might as well call the hash a password.

Comment: @mario If you go down that road, http + https login page is also vulnerable. An attacker could intercept the http request and change the form action from "https://..." to "http://...". Nothing is entirely safe except encrypting everything.

Comment: @Artefacto The website would supply a nonce which is different every time, and is hashed together with the password. This guards against a replay attack.

Comment: @Sjoerd Then you're implementing a simple version of digest authentication, which is not what "encrypt the password using Javascript" conveys. "message digest" != "cyphertext", "encrypt" generally denotes building cyphertext from plain text, not applying a hash algorithm.